# Getting sintax error while import dump into postgresql in Linux

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

I installed Postgresql on the Redhat Linux server and try to import the dump into the database At that time I'll get a syntax error.

> sudo -u postgres -i psql db_test < data.sql

> psql -h localhost -U postgres -W -d postgres < data.sql

Iam used these two commands to import data. At that time I'll get syntax error like this.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comment_details`;
                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `comment_details` (
                     ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: LOCK TABLES `comment_details` WRITE;
                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `comment_details` VALUES (3,1140,'ANAKAPALLI MAN...
                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNLOCK"
LINE 1: UNLOCK TABLES;
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `directory_org_details`;
                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `directory_org_details` (
                     ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: LOCK TABLES `directory_org_details` WRITE;
                    ^
invalid command \'s
invalid command \'s
invalid command \'s
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `directory_org_details` VALUES (1,'Daniel\'s Cri...
```

Please Help regarding This issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Those dreaded backticks are non-standard SQL and invalid in Postgres. It looks like you are trying to run a SQL script that was intended for MySQL

Comment: You can't generally import SQL code from one DBMS into another because everything's different enough to make it fail: syntax, statements, column types...

Comment: I want to import mysql dump to postgresql. So, it is possible or not. iF it is possible what is the process. please Let me know it is very important to me.